# Reading from mushaf or Quran app in voluntary prayers?

Tags: quran, salat, fiqh

Salam

I have seen a few videos on YouTube which say this is allowed in voluntary prayers such tahhajud etc.. I want to know if anyone else has done this and when going into sujood how does one hold the mushaf or phone if reading from app? Do we still have to have right hand over left if holding mushaf/phone if reciting like this?

Can this be done in sunnah prayers too?

I want to do this to make my salah longer as I don't know know a lot of surahs from memory.

Comment: Sunnah prayers are equivalent to Nafl / voluntary prayers when it comes to rulings. So I think it applies to both. However, I would think the ruling is there to enable those who don't yet know enough Quran by heart to be able to prayer whole learning. I would encourage you to rather recite what yiu know by heart, and work on memorising more. However, it's even better if you understand what you memorise/recite.

Comment: Jazakallah brother

Answer (score 0):

You can place a chair or table next to you to place the Mushaf when you bow and prostrate
to free your hands. When performing Sajda Tilawaat (Reaching an Ayah of prostration and prostrating) you can hold the Kitaab between your upper hand and body so as to free both hands to perform Sajda.

Comment: Jazakallah I did think I could do this thanks for confirmation !!